# Can't compile Spring Roo project when using Nexus

Tags: maven, spring-roo, nexus

Can't compile Spring Roo (1.2.3.RELEASE) project when using Nexus.

mvn says can't find roo.annotations:jar

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Roo123: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example.roo:Roo123:jar:0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.springframework.roo:org.springframework.roo.annotations:jar:1.2.3.RELEASE in http://192.168.16.232:8081/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

However this jar is already in local maven repository.

When disabling Nexus, by renaming .m2\settings.xml, it works fine.

settings.xml has just 1 mirror configured

```
<mirror>
  <id>nexus</id>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  <url>http://192.168.16.232:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</mirror>
```

How to configure Nexus?

(Adding http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release as proxy repository doesn't help)

UPDATE: add picture. Adding spring-roo-repository on the left side doesn't help. 
Two long answeres below doesn't help either.

[image: Nexus public]

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to configuration a mirrorof only you have to configure the following:

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Apart from your configuration you need to delete your local repository and retry the build. Have you configured Nexus correctly to have access to the internet like maven central etc. ?

Comment: I don't understand. Why do I need create profile and make it active?
What is the sense of <id>central</id> when everything is already in content/groups/public ? And deleting  local repository (if it is not corrupted) is generally bad advice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have admin access to your Nexus install, but you have to add [a new proxy repository](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/config-sect-new-repo.html) to your Nexus install.

The repo you have to add is

```
http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release
```

You should have a settings file like below (slightly different than khmarbaise's version):

```
<settings
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
      <servers>  
          <server>  
              <id>central</id>  
              <username>your-user</username>  
              <password>your-user</password>  
          </server>  
          <server>  
              <id>mirror</id>  
              <username>your-user</username>  
              <password>your-user</password>  
          </server>  
      </servers>  
      <mirrors>  
        <mirror>  
            <id>mirror</id>  
            <url>https://url.to.your.nexus</url>  
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>  
        </mirror>  
      </mirrors>  
      <profiles>  
          <profile>  
              <id>defaultprofile</id>  
              <repositories>  
                  <repository>  
                      <id>central</id>  
                    <name>Repository for your artifacts</name>  
                      <url>https://url.to.your.nexus</url>  
                      <releases>  
                          <enabled>true</enabled>  
                    </releases>  
                      <snapshots>  
                          <enabled>true</enabled>  
                    </snapshots>  
                  </repository>  
              </repositories>  
              <pluginRepositories>  
                  <pluginRepository>  
                      <id>central</id>  
                    <name>Repository for your artifacts</name>  
                      <url>https://url.to.your.nexus</url>  
                      <releases>  
                          <enabled>true</enabled>  
                    </releases>  
                      <snapshots>  
                          <enabled>true</enabled>  
                    </snapshots>  
                  </pluginRepository>  
              </pluginRepositories>  
              <properties>  
                  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>  
              </properties>  
              <activation>  
                  <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>  
              </activation>  
          </profile>  
      </profiles>  
      <activeProfiles>  
          <activeProfile>defaultprofile</activeProfile>  
      </activeProfiles>  
</settings>
```

You have to override `central` (see above), so that Maven won't connect to the default `central` (`repo1.maven.org`).